# RSS friendly HTML for magazine-like quote layouts

Tags: html, semantics

My question is only about magazine-like quotes, such as the one you can find on on [theverge.com](http://www.theverge.com/2013/3/22/4134580/microsoft-defends-windows-rt-fails-to-answer-criticisms) for instance.

[image: screenshot of a magazine-like quote]

It may be done with `blockquote` or `q` but since it often repeats parts of the content and really part of the layout, it doesn't really make sense to have them in the RSS feeds, neither it does for SEO.

I would like to know what is the **best practice** for keeping this kind of layout, and have a clean RSS feed.

Comment: Also posted the question there: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/16980/9563

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called [pull quote](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pull_quote).

You shouldn't use [`blockquote`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-blockquote-element) or [`q`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-q-element) for this, because the content is *not*

> quoted from another source.

(Only if you'd use a pull quote that is part of an interview etc., i.e. if the original content itself is quoted, you could use `blockquote`/`q`.)

The [`aside` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-aside-element) is appropriate here:

> The element can be used for typographical effects like **pull quotes** […]

Now you could decide to remove all `aside` elements (that are childs of the `article`) for the feed.

Or you could only remove those with a certain class, e.g.: `<aside class="pull-quote">…</aside>`

Or you keep them. I think they *can* have a value. They can be an eyecatcher, similar to headings. If someone scrolls through a longer feed entry, such pull quotes will typically stand out (new lines before and after), so they'd be read first probably, and may get the reader interested to read that section in detail.

Comment: Thank you very much for such a comprehensive answer. I see your point,  but is allowed to have `aside` elements inside an `article`?

Comment: @TKrugg: Yes, of course. If you put an `aside` *in* an `article`, the content of the `aside` has to be "tangentially related" to the content around it, that is, the `article` content. If you put an `aside` as a child of `body`, the content would have to be "tangentially related" to the whole page. So for a pull quote, you'd *have* to place the `aside` inside of the `article`.